# Not able to submit a form via Ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, popup

EDIT

the code below seems to works as long as the form is valid.

but when it is not the case (clean method in django form) h1 text of form is removed (????) and the error messages are not displayed...

I guess that an empty popup.html is return via ajax and as there is no button to interact with nothing happen but why h1 text is removed...???

```
   var prevent_edit = false;
    var prevent = false;

    // popup d'informations indiquant que la levée d'insue a déjà été faite 
    // pour ce patient
    $("#form_unblind_edit").submit(function (event) {
        console.log('form_unblind_edit click - first')
        console.log('prevent_edit - first', prevent_edit)
        if (!prevent_edit) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }


    // affichage des informations sur le patient sélectionné pour la ré-allocation
    $("#unblind_edit").on("click", function (event) {
        console.log('click unblind edit');
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var patient = $("#id_pat").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/unblind/already_unblind/',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'patient': patient,
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('success');
                // var prevent_edit = false;
                $("#can_unblind").html(data);
                $('#unblindconfirm').modal('show');

                $('body').on('click', '#edit_button_OK', function (event) {
                    console.log('edit_button_OK')
                    $('#edit_button_OK').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    prevent_edit = true;
                    console.log('prevent_edit', prevent_edit);
                    $("#form_unblind_edit").submit();
                })
            },
            error: function (resultat, statut, erreur) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });

    });
```

---

i need some help for popup with ajax

User complete the form and submit the form by clicking a button

I prevent submit with `event.preventDefault();` to display a popup.

But I need to ask database for informations to display on popup, so I use an ajax query

when ajax success, popup is displayed with informations from database and I want the form t be submited by clicking on "OK" button of the popup

but it failed, I think, because event (submit) is attached to a button that is not present in DOM when page load...

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var prevent_edit = false;

    // prevent submission
    $("#form_unblind_edit").submit(function (event) {
        if (!prevent_edit) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    // ajax query that display popup
    $("#unblind_edit").on("click", function (event) {
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var patient = $("#id_pat").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/unblind/already_unblind/',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'patient': patient,
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#can_unblind").html(data); //popup html attach to DOM
                $('#unblindconfirm').modal('show');  //popup displayed
                $('body').on('click', '#edit_button_OK', function (event) {
                    console.log('edit_button_OK'); // WORKING
                    prevent_edit = true;
                    $("#form_unblind_edit").trigger('submit');  //form submission = NOT WORKING
                })
            }

        });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.submit()` instead of `.trigger('submit')` ?

Comment: yes but does the same

Comment: have you tried console.log inside submit function to check if it gets called? Also you could log prevent_edit inside there and make sure it is set to true

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the type of the submit button in the form to "button"

```
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

This way the submit action is not executed when the user clicks submit and instead you display the popup. Then you should be able to submit the form using JQuery.

```
 $("#form_unblind_edit").trigger('submit');
```

Comment: thanks for replying but doesn't solved the issue